# Exact derivation of Von Kármán relation of Gauss curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces

Using relations for surface deformations (in structural mechanics notation)

$$ u,v,{\epsilon _x, \epsilon_y, \gamma_{xy}}$$

Notations {u,v  } have same meaning as displacements in surface theory.

They are related   as:

$$\epsilon_x= u_{,x},  \epsilon_y= v_ {,_y},  \,\gamma_{xy} =u_{,y}+v_{,x} \tag{1} $$

EDIT3:

Typo in the above sign of last shear term rectified.

one derives an approximate relation for Gauss curvature K

$$ -( rt-s^2 )=({\epsilon _x,}_{yy} +{\epsilon_y,}_{xx}- \gamma_{xy, x,y,} )\tag{2}$$

EDIT2:

which is defined as compatibility equation as if K = 0 always and  sacrosanct. However K does not  vanish for deep shells with large $ p,q $ geometric non-linearity. When analysing shallow shells $ K= 0 $ is considered sufficiently accurate for engineering mechanics calculations!

In case of Monge form of surface $ z= f(x,y)$ we have exactly

$$ K= \frac{LN-M ^2}{EG-F^2} =\frac{rt-s^2}{(1+p^2+q^2)^2}\tag{3}$$

How do we derive the exact relationship of K and strain differentials including (without discarding ) the denominator in right hand side of Equation (2)?

EDIT1

Vanishing Gauss curvature is a condition of compatibility for small rotations. It is equivalent to Kirchoff's Law that plane sections remain plane after deformation. As the simple example for shallow line curvature the formula $ \frac{y^{''} }{(1+y{'2})^ \frac32} \approx y^{''}$. It is sufficient in Engineer's linear theory but not when differential geometrical methods are used. Classical differential geometry provides an opportunity to express the full $ K$ without needing to neglect $ p,q$ compared to 1. It is like settling/ compromising for K definition as $ (LN-M ^2) $ only.

Negative sign of $ \gamma $ derivative is okay when brought to left hand side as given Timoshenko's text book.Definitions of strains as per equation 1 . Bronchi's formula is pure differential geometry. It does not relate to the three strains accurately i.e., mathematically.

A classical reference:

[Influence of curvature on Buckling of shells by Th. v. Karman](http://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/8.1123?journalCode=jans)

Comment: I have no idea what the phrase "same meaning as displacements in surface theory" mean. Please give either a link to a reference explaining the so-called "structural mechanics notation", or include the definition in your post. I suspect once the notations are clarified the answer is not too hard to arrive at.

Comment: The first reference is Theory of Elasticity, SP Timoshenko a well referenced author. It used to be fully available in google books. The sequel book is    http://155.207.34.6/files/Timoshenko.pdf. The question relates to non-linear theory of geometric strain and compound curvature K. Shall be on look out and give link to a good reference  if all essential equations are available at one place. u,v are parametrization length coordinates for 3D surfaces.

Comment: Timoshenko's book seems to give a plus sign instead of a minus sign in the definition of $\gamma_{xy}$, can you confirm?

Comment: Furthermore, given the corrected definitions, $\epsilon_{x,yy} + \epsilon_{y,xx} = u_{,xyy} + v_{,yxx} = \gamma_{xy,xy}$ so the expression on line (2) is identically zero. This actually agrees with Pg 24 of Timoshenko's book that you referred to. // Please edit the question to provide a precise reference to the mechanical/geometric set-up and provide a clear description of your question.

Comment: In particular, is your question answered by applying the [Brioschi formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_curvature#Alternative_formulas) for Gauss curvature to some metric tensor? As to what the metric tensor should be in terms of $\epsilon_x, \epsilon_y, \gamma_{xy}$, it depends on the actual geometric/physical definition of those three quantities chosen.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments. I have included in the main area my response in main edit as comments space here is limited.

Comment: In some texts shear notation given as $   \epsilon_{xy}  =\gamma _{xy}/2 .$

Comment: I got an impression that expression for $K$ was never taken to the finish line.. However, my access to literature Is quite limited.

Comment: When I said "sign" in $\gamma_{xy}$, I meant that in Timoshenko it is written that $\gamma_{xy} = u_y + v_x$, whereas you wrote $u_y - v_x$. The two are quite different. // Quote "It does not relate to the three strains accurately i.e., mathematically." You have not yet defined what the three strains should be mathematically. You need to do that.

Comment: Basically, I suspect that if you take $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be the material manifold, and $u: \mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}^3$ the displacement, then you can take the function $\phi = \mathrm{Id} + u$ which gives a diffeomorphism from your material manifold to its image in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then the strain tensor should be $\epsilon = \phi^* \delta - \delta$ where $\phi^*\delta$ is the pullback Riemannian metric and $\delta$ the Euclidean metric.  In this case you can directly apply the Brioschi formula.

Comment: What I just wrote is a translation of [a modern geometric theory](https://eudml.org/doc/76802) for nonlinear elastodynamics. The key is that even at the level of defining $\epsilon_x = u_{,x}$ you are already linearizing. And if you want a consistent nonlinear theory you have to forget about that definition and write down something geometric and natural. If there is another definition that you are using, please feel free to edit the question and include it.

Comment: Sorry for shear term typo that caused needless confusion. I would get  back after the strain non-linearity is fully applied at its definitive level, meanwhile moderator should kindly keep it open.

Comment: The $ -R_{1212} $ should be connected with a non-linear $ \epsilon_x - u_{,x} $ relation using Brionchi formula. I do not know what curvilinear net should be employed.

Comment: @WillieWong: I would suggest a geometric/natural form be assumed that  is needed to be assumed either implicit or explicitly, before proceeding with Brioschi relations to result in classical theory expression for Gauss curvature. Gauss-Codazzi relations are after all another way of expressing Karman compatibility relations without explicit definition of strain components brought in at intermediate stage..which link first fundamental (christoffel coeffts) with second fundamental form derivatives.

Comment: Compatibility condition expressed in polar ( cylindrical / spherical ) coordinates  along with geodesic polar coordinate equations could offer an  easier key for connecting the three types of strain tensors fully to classical surface theory.